# error: "expected an expression" I am trying to use array in function

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, expression

```
void phage :: evaluate(bacteria ba[]) {

    for (int i = 0; i<popsize; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j<gensize; j++)
            fitness += m[i] == ba[i].m[j];
}
```

> here is an evaluate function, declared in struct. when I try to call it, there is an error "expected an expression"

```
for (int i = 0; i < popsize; i++)
    population[i].evaluate(population[]);
```

Comment: remove `[]` from `population[i].evaluate(population[]);`

Comment: the error appears in population []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < popsize; i++)
    population[i].evaluate(population[]);
```

use

```
for (int i = 0; i < popsize; i++)
    population[i].evaluate(population);
```